Rerouting to a specific page if the logged in user is not authorized to access the page
I am currently implementing the OAuth2.0 authentication and authorization with AzureAD in my Blazor application, and I'm facing some troubles.
For example, if the logged in user is not authenticated to access the 'Admin' page, it gets redirected to https://localhost:7155/MicrosoftIdentity/Account/AccessDenied?ReturnUrl=admin, and gives me 404 response. What I want it to happen is to get redirected to https://localhost:7155/AccessDenied instead.
I put the attribute
@attribute[Route("Admin")]
@attribute [Authorize(Policy = "Admin")]

on top of the .razor page that I'm working on right now.
In Routes.razor, I also added the following:
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="routeData" DefaultLayout="typeof(Layout.MainLayout)" >
             <NotAuthorized>
                     <AccessDenied />
                 </NotAuthorized>
        </AuthorizeRouteView>
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
        <NotFound>
    <AccessDenied />
    </NotFound>

Any suggestion/idea would be appreciated.

Nitpick: a user is or is not authorized to access an admin page. Authentication is proving identity. Authorization is proving permissions.

According to your description it is blazor8 you are using and it is kind of a common problem since blazor 8. There have been discussions about this issue https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/52063.
The Microsoft document provides the explanation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/render-modes?view=aspnetcore-8.0#static-server-side-rendering-static-ssr
During static SSR, Razor component page requests are processed by server-side ASP.NET Core middleware pipeline request processing for routing and authorization. Dedicated Blazor features for routing and authorization aren't operational because Razor components aren't rendered during server-side request processing. Blazor router features in the Routes component that aren't available during static SSR include displaying:
Not authorized content (...) (NotAuthorized):
Blazor Web Apps typically process unauthorized requests on the server by customizing the behavior of Authorization Middleware.
Not found content (...) (NotFound):
Blazor Web Apps typically process bad URL requests on the server by either displaying the browser's built-in 404 UI or returning a custom 404 page (or other response) via ASP.NET Core middleware (for example, UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects / API documentation).
There are some workarounds but they cannot make the middleware logic work on blazor framework level, so we recommend you not trying to do so.
